# Linux console changed, print OK, read NOK

Tags: linux, console, kernel, tty, cmdline-args

I'm working on a small embedded linux platform at the office where I have to change the default console from ttyS0 to another ttySx.
The ttyS0 is enabled and is the default console. 
I enabled the other ttyS, successfully probed it, I've given it the ID=4, which means now I can see it properly as /dev/ttyS4.

So I modified the cmdline from:

```
CMDLINE=...console=ttyS0,921600n8 console=tty0...
```

to

```
CMDLINE=...console=ttyS4,921600n8 console=tty0...
```

The uarts are connected to FTDI chips.
With console=ttyS0 I can successfully read/write on this shell.
With console=ttyS4 I can see what the kernel prints, but whatever I write is ignored by linux.

So I checked the TX/RX of the new ttyS4. I have opened a putty session on this com port. Logging in over ssh to have access to linux file system i did few tests:

```
echo 1234 > /dev/ttyS4        
echo 1234 > /dev/console
```

Both above commands successfully print "1234" on the putty window corresponding to the ttyS4.

Then:

```
cat /dev/console             
cat /dev/ttyS4
```

Both above cat commands display successfully what I type & ENTER on my putty window.
That means the electrical connections as well as the driver for ttyS4 are working well.
However, if I try to access the file system in this putty window, I can't. Typing enter will just print a new empty line, nothing else.
It's like the new console=ttyS4 doesn't forward the data I write to the linux.

I can see the new `console=ttyS4,921600n8 console=tty0` when I type cat /proc/cmdline

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a getty running on this console?

Comment: No, that was the issue, i wasn't aware I have to start manually the getty on the new defined console. I just added the entry in /etc/inittab and I have it working. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consoles are just input and output devices. If you want to use them for shell logins, start a `getty` on them.

With SysVinit, you can do this by editing `/etc/inittab` and copying or uncommenting a line there:

```
4:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty4
```

With systemd, you can run

```
systemctl enable console-getty.service getty@tty4.service
```